# Ethernet frames smaller than 64 bytes

Tags: networking, ethernet

By IEEE 802.3, an Ethernet frame has to carry a payload of at least 46 bytes. This is for collision detection-- collisions of smaller frames (may) go undetected.

The Q is: what if the payload to be carried is shorter? what kind of padding is used to scale the frame up to the slot size-- 64 bytes?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from [Data and Computer Network Communication](http://www.laxmipublications.com/servlet/lpgetbiblio?bno=000274) (emphasis mine);

> If the network layer wishes to send less than 46 bytes of data **the MAC protocol adds sufficient number of zero bytes (0x00, is also known as null padding characters)** to satisfy the requirement.

Some buggy drivers fail to do this though [as noted by Adaptec](http://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5133/~/how-does-adaptec-drivers-handle-ethernet-frame-padding%3F).